# What Happens When Force Ghosts Die?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

The Wookieepedia article on the [Netherworld of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Netherworld_of_the_Force) has very few details, but in the article on [Force ghosts](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_ghost), there's a little more.

I'm not completely clear, but it seems to say that Qui-Gon died and went to the Netherworld of the Force, but was helped back by a Whill shaman, and after that, he helped other Jedi, as they died, avoid the trip to the Netherworld of the Force.  This implies that when Qui-Gon died and went to the Netherworld, he maintained enough of his own individuality and self awareness to find his way back, apparently either intact or mostly intact.

But Force ghosts eventually have to go to the Netherworld of the Force, because all things die (but apparently one Whill Shaman found a way to be immortal).

This leads to two related questions:

1) Why do Force ghosts have to leave for the Netherworld of the Force?

2) What happens when one goes to the Netherworld?

If Qui-Gon has been there and it's known that Yoda met two people there, then there must still be some sense of individuality in the Netherworld.  Is it the Force equivalent of the Summerlands or heaven or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

It's uncertain because Star Wars has so much conflicting canon. In early works it's implied that when you die, you lose your sense of self and merge with the Force indefinitely, unlike a select few who learned to retain their consciousness within the Force. Then you have the Lake of Apparitions, which shows everybody including Jacen Solo, adding more confusion.

However, the best source for me is Timothy Zahn's *Heir to the Empire*. Obi-Wan's ghost appears to Luke in a dream, telling him he can no longer contact him, and now needs to move on to whatever life their is beyond, implying that he doesn't know what will happen when he gets to the Other side. That fits the best for me. We don't know, and we don't find out till later. The reason why Jedi have such an atheist view of life beyond death, is that they don't concern themselves with such things, prefering to focus on the here and now, and what's going on in this world.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is where Qui-Gon went, but Luke was able to talk to Mara and Jacen who were in the [Lake of Apparitions](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lake_of_Apparitions) in the *Fate of the Jedi* books.